# What would be the impact of using a TreeSet<Integer> with a comparator that allows duplicates

Tags: java, binary-tree, comparator, treeset

### The problem (No binary tree with duplicates in java collections).

I need a binary tree with duplicates, I need the O(Log(n)) complexity of searching and insertion while keeping the order (so i can't use Hash tables), java doesn't have a collection that implements a binary tree and allow duplicates while keeping all binary tree operations.

### Can we use TreeSet to do this?

I'm trying to tweak TreeSet and allow duplicates by passing a comparator that never returns 0. I know this won't be a set anymore but it's ok, i need duplicates.

Example

```java
TreeSet<Integer> binaryTreeWithDuplicates = new TreeSet<Integer>((x, y) -> x>y?1:-1);
```

Will there be an undesirable side effect of such implementation and usage?
because we are obviously violating the rules in [comparator api](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare%28T,%20T%29) like the sign rule.

Comment: A Set can’t have duplicates, so you don’t want a Set.  I suggest using a List, and always keeping the List sorted by using [Collections.binarySearch](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#binarySearch(java.util.List,T)) to determine the insert point for each new element.  (You could also sort the entire List frequently, but that’s going perform poorly.)

Comment: @Progman I modified the question, I specified the X, and then discussed a possible Y while asking for the side effects of such a Y. (for more on xy problem https://xyproblem.info/ .thanks btw that was informative)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`contains` would never return `true`.

You could have arbitrary duplicates in the set, and not be able to identify or remove them.  (`remove` would never work.)

Comment: Yes this is a very undesirable side effect, i was aiming to create a binary tree with dups but keeping contains, remove... It seems to not be possible using this class, they use compareTo to do all the operations and we can't override that.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest trying a [TreeMultiset](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#multiset) instead

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I was trying to stick to the use of java collection api. but it doesn't seem possible, i have to either implement it myself or use a third party library.

Answer (score 0):

Opinion:

Your Set ceases to be a Set, for one thing.  Since that's outside the specification, the implementation is not obliged to do anything consistently.  Anything could happen.

Note that since you can't say 2 == 2, you're obliged to have 2 > 2 at the same time that 2 < 2.  That doesn't seem like it will end happily.

The only way to discover what happens with this sort of abuse is to try it.  Maybe it'll all work and allow duplicate entries. But that doesn't guarantee that it will continue to happen with the next bugfix.

If I needed something like this (though I don't understand your use case), I'd either build a special-purpose class, or else try and use something like a set of lists of numbers.